# German word for “complete”

Tags: word-choice

I want to know the best German words for “complete” in the meaning of “equipped with all factory optionals”, to characterize vehicles like bikes, automobiles or motorbikes.

Comment: komplett? --- What did your research bring up and why weren't you satisfied with the results?

Comment: I have found many words with the meaning of "complete" in german, like voll, vollständig, sämlich, and did not know what to use for this meaning.

Comment: @Takkat In English neither. You can't say "a complete car". But you would say "a fully equipped car", for instance. So you need to find a translation for equipment (Ausstattung) and then you add the adjective. And there–surprise, surprise–"komplett" and "vollständig" are absolutely fine. – And this is exactly what you did say in your answer. Except that you're missing the most obvious translation "komplett". "Komplettausstattung" is also a valid word, which is used often, too.

Comment: @Em1: *Komplettausstattung* is used in the sense of having all equipment rather than in the sense of a complete single item.

Comment: @Takkat Huh? I don't understand what you're saying. I don't see any difference in those terms. And actually the question is about "having all equipments". So, "Komplettausstattung" is fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the context of a fully equipped device/vehicle we mostly say *"Vollausstattung"*, *"mit allen Extras"*, or use an adverbial construct *voll ausgestattet*.

> Ein voll ausgestattetes Fahrrad.
>    Audi mit Vollausstattung, Baujahr 2011, zu verkaufen.
>    Unseren neuen Wohnwagen haben wir mit allen Extras gekauft.

Comment: In this context, *Komplettausstattung* is just fine, or any other combination with *komplett* for that matter.

Comment: @Grantwalzer this should be another answer! How about you make it one?